# Transform some kind of exponential distribution into normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following exponential distribution, generated with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

np.random.seed(1)
tags_ratio = np.random.exponential(1/25, 1000)
plt.hist(tags_ratio, range=(0, 1), bins=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm trying to transform my data, resides in `tags_ratio` into normal distribution, but with no success.

Tried with the log function and square functions. it given decent results. But I'm interesting in more ideas. Maybe more sophisticated.

Comment: Have you tried log transformation?

Comment: Yeah I'm currently doing it with the log.. It's not that normal but it might be sufficient. Anyway I'm interested in more ideas

Comment: have you tried with boxcox?

Comment: boxcox results doing something similar the sqrt does. It leaves the 0 value hanged high and totally out of the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to see if this helps:

```
from scipy.stats import boxcox
tags_ratio = boxcox(tags_ratio, 0.3)
plt.hist(tags_ratio)
plt.show()
```

**result:**

[image]

for more explanations and theory about Box-Cox [click here.](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/transformations/box-cox.html)

Comment: boxcox is nice. I went with log10 but might change it to boxcox when the time is right..